# Legendre symbol, how to compute the value of the form $\displaystyle\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From the textbook, we know $\displaystyle\left(\frac{2}{p}\right)=(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}$. But I just see a case seems this formula doens't work.

[image]

For $p \equiv2 (mod3)$, $(-1)^{(p^2-1)/8}=(-1)^{3/8}=(-1)^{1/8}$. How can we get $-1$ finally?

Comment: You're trying to mix congruences mod  3 and congruences mod 8!

Comment: $$\left(\frac23\right)=(-1)^{(3^2-1)/8}=(-1)^{8/8}=-1,$$ so the formula gives $-1$ as claimed. What is the problem again? Did you think that $p$ in $\left(\dfrac p3\right)$ is the same as the $p$ in $\left(\dfrac 2p\right)$? Why would you think that way?

Comment: @Bernard Oh, I see. I thought $p=2$. Actually $p$ is 3 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that just because $p\equiv 2\pmod3$, that doesn't mean that $p^2-1 = 3$. For instance, for $p = 5$, we have $p^2 - 1 = 24$ and $(-1)^{(p^2 - 1)/8} = (-1)^{24/8} = (-1)^3 = -1$.

Also, as commented above, the two formulas are for different things. One is for $\left(\frac 2p\right)$, while the other is for $\left(\frac p3\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Also see [Using gauss's lemma to find $(\frac{n}{p})$ (Legendre Symbol)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819) where you can find a proof of $$(\frac{2}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p^2-1}{8}}$$ or, equivalent, $$(\frac{2}{p})=1 \iff p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 8$$