# Proof that $5$ is a quadratic residue $(\mod p)$ with $p$ odd prime iif $p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 10$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, legendre-symbol

Here I present the following proof in order to receive corrections or any kind of suggestion to improve my handling/knowledge of modular arithmetic:

> Prove that $5$ is a quadratic residue $(\mod p)$ with $p$ odd prime
>   iif $p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 10$ ; prove also that $5$ is NOT a quadratic residue $(\mod p)$
>   iif $p \equiv \pm 3 \mod 10$.

*Dim:*

To check if $5$ is a quadratic residue $(\mod p)$ I write the equivalent Legendre symbol with the condition:

$(5/p) = 1$

So I have for quadratic reciprocity $(5/p) = (p/5)(-1)^{{(p-1)(5-1)}\over 4}=(p/5)(-1)^{(p-1)}$

$\bullet$ The exponent $(p-1)$ must be $(\mod2)$

$\bullet$ $(p/5)$ means to find $p$ : $p(\mod5)$ $\rightarrow$ the choices are $1,3(\mod5)$ because $p$ is prime

The moduli are coprime $(2,5)=1$ so I can study for the two final cases $(\mod5\times 2)=(\mod10)$

**Case $1(\mod10)$:**

Here $(1/5)=1$ and for the exponent $p=1(\mod2)$ so the exponent $(p-1)$ must be even. So $(5/p)=1$ for  $p=1(\mod10)$ but also for  $p=-1(\mod10)$

**Case $3(\mod10)$:**

Here $(3/5)=-1$ because it's not a quadratic residue, and for the exponent $p=3(\mod2)=1(\mod2)$ so the exponent $(p-1)$ must be even. So $(5/p)=(-1)(1)=-1$ for  $p=3(\mod10)$ but also for  $p=-3(\mod10)$

$\Box$

I appreciate any kind of critics and corrections.

Thank you

Comment: There are more cases.  A prime can be $2$ or $4 \pmod{5}.$.

Comment: I've excluded 2 and 4 because p must be prime and odd; is it formally wrong to exclude them in this way a-priori?

Comment: Notice that $7 \equiv 2 \pmod{5}$ and $19\equiv 4 \pmod{5}$.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll review the proof with your suggestions, I hope to edit it for the final version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my other post [use Gauss lemma to find $(\frac{n}{p})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819):

$(\frac{5}{p}) = 1 \iff p \equiv \pm 1 \mod 5$