# Legendre Symbol (2/p)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation

This is a proof from Burton's Number Theory.

Theorem: If $p$ is an odd prime, then $(2/p)= \begin{cases} 1,  & \text{if $p =
 1 (\mod 8)$ or $7 (\mod 8)$}  \\
 -1, & \text{if $p = 3 (\mod 8)$ or $5 (\mod 8)$}\end{cases}$\

According to Gauss' lemma, $(2/p)=(-1)^n$, where $n$ is the number of integers in the set 
\begin{align*}
 S=\{1\cdot 2, 2\cdot 2,3\cdot 2,...,(\frac{p-1}{2})\cdot 2\}
\end{align*} 
which upon division by $p$, have remainders greater than $p/2$. The members of $S$ are all less than $p$, so that it suffices to count the number that exceed $p/2$.
For $1\leq  k\leq (p-1)/2$, we have $2k<p/2$ if and only if $k<p/4$. If $[ ]$ denotes the greatest integer function, then there are $[p/4]$ integers in $S$ less than $p/2$; hence,
\begin{align*}
 n=\frac{p-1}{2}-[\frac{p}{4}]
\end{align*} 
is the number of integers that are greater than $p/2$.\ 
Now, we have four possibilities; for any odd prime has one of the form $8k+1, 8k+3, 8k+5,$ or $8k+7$.

This is where I got confused:\
(1) For $1\leq  k\leq (p-1)/2$, we have $2k<p/2$ if and only if $k<p/4$.\
(2) If $[ ]$ denotes the greatest integer function, then there are $[p/4]$ integers in $S$ less than $p/2$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Exactly what is confusing here? This is a standard proof, which looks perfectly clear to me...

Comment: How to show that for $1\leq  k\leq (p-1)/2$, we have $2k<p/2$ if and only if $k<p/4$.

Comment: What's the problem with just dividing both sides of $2k<p/2$ by $2$, to get $k<p/4$?

Comment: Ok how about the other one? (2)

Comment: Maybe, I misunderstand your question - but the other inequality ($1\le k\le(p-1)/2$) is irrelevant here: $2k<p/2$ if and only if $k<p/4$, regardless of what else is true or false. This does not create any problems with the argument.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer on a similar question: [Using gauss's lemma to find $(\frac{n}{p})$ (Legendre Symbol)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819)

This hopefully clarifies to you how Gauss' lemma can best be used to calculate $(\frac{n}{p})$.