# quadratic residue such as "$(n|p)= -1$"(quadratic reciprocity)

Tags: number-theory, legendre-symbol, quadratic-reciprocity

(Note: (n|p)=1 is legendre-symbol.)

So need to find primes where $(n|p)=1$ So we have

1- $1\pmod 4$ where we use quadratic residue of $n$ along with $\pmod n$ to find solutions.

2- Then we have $3\pmod 4$ where we use quadratic nonresidues of $n$ again with $(\!\bmod  n)$  to find more solutions.

3-We combine solutions from 1 and 2 to get all primes in the form of $$p\equiv  \langle \text{solutions-from-above}\rangle\pmod{4\times n} $$

But how to do we go about solving some thing with $'-1'$ like
$ (n|p)  = -1 $
for example $ (3|p) = -1 $ or $(2|p)=-1$.

Or some thing with more solutions as $(5|p)=-1$.

Examples from the book:.

in the book it says.

$(2|p) \equiv 1$ gives $p \equiv 1 (mod 8)$.

$(2|p) \equiv -1$ gives $p \equiv 3 (mod 8)$.

$(3|p) \equiv 1$ gives $p \equiv 1 (mod 12)$'

$(3|p) \equiv -1$ gives $p \equiv 7 (mod 12)$.

Thank you.

Comment: quadratic reciprocity?

Comment: What do you denote$(n|p)$? Legendre's symbol?

Comment: its Quadratic reciprocity, and (n|p) is Legendre symbol.

Comment: Is $n$ any integer, or a prime?

Comment: in the question n is prime.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer to another question where $(\frac{n}{p})$  is determined by applying Gauss' criterium: 
[Using gauss's lemma to find $(\frac{n}{p})$ (Legendre Symbol)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819)