# How do you evaluate the quadratic residue of 7 mod p?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues, legendre-symbol

How do you evaluate this quadratic residue? I've been playing around with some specific values and I suspect 1 if p is of the form 28k+/-1, 3, 9 and -1 if 28k+/- 5, 11, 13. I have no idea how to come up with those though. Any help is well appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with quadratic reciprocity (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity)?

Comment: @AnuragA I am not, unfortunately

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258707

Comment: @user328442 well then, either you can try to learn quadratic reciprocity or you can use Gauss's lemma to compute $\left(\frac{n}{p}\right)$. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819

Comment: @barto this is very helpful. I didn't see it earlier, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get your result is to apply Gauss' lemma, see [Using gauss's lemma to find $(\frac{n}{p})$ (Legendre Symbol)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267785/using-gausss-lemma-to-find-fracnp-legendre-symbol/1418819#1418819).
Another way is to apply the quadratic residue theorem, which implies that $(\frac{7}{p})=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}(\frac{p}{7})$. From there the route to the result is easy.